# Norm of a linear functional from $C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Given $T:C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $Tf=\int_0^1f(t)dt$. Prove that $||T||=1$.

Now I know that $|Tf|=|\int_0^1f(t)dt|\leq\int_0^1|f(t)|dt\leq||f||_{\infty}$

Now how do I prove that $||T||\nless1$

Comment: By finding a function $f$ such that $\|f\|_{\infty} = |Tf|$.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of norm of an operator we have $\|T\| \geq |Tf|$ for any $f$ such that $\|f\|_{\infty}\leq 1$. Take $f$ to be the constant function $1$. You get $\|T\|\geq T1=\int_0^{1} 1 dt=1$.